# Listview merged together at run time if data is not there

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I 'm designing one layout consist of two listviews(image 1) but when data is not there both listview getting merged(image 2).Can anyone help me out to get rid of this.Here I'm attaching my xml snippet.Please guys have a look over it and please tell me where i'm wrong.

Your precious time will be appreciated.

Image1

[image]

Image 2

[image]
layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_green"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_mseTitle"
        style="@style/pageTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/mseTitle" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/txt_mseView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_mseTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#2E9AFE" />

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_msefull"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_mseView"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_mseOrder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >


             <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/mse_radioCustImpBasedOn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/mse_radioCustOrderno"
                    style="@style/textRegular"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:button="@drawable/radiobutton_selector"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="@string/mse_order_no" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/mse_radioCustno"
                    style="@style/textRegular"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:button="@drawable/radiobutton_selector"
                    android:text="@string/mse_customer_no" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_msecategory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lay_mseOrder"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mse_custtxtCategory"
                style="@style/textRegular"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".27"
                android:text="@string/msecategory" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/mse_spnCustCategory"
                style="@style/SpinnerDropDownItemAppTheme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
                android:layout_weight=".23"
               />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mse_custtxtfilter"
                style="@style/textRegular"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".27"
                android:text="@string/msefilter" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/mse_spnCustFilter"
                style="@style/SpinnerDropDownItemAppTheme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight=".23"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mse_edtCustValue"
            style="@style/EditTextAppTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/mseentervalue" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            style="@style/textRegular_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mse_edtCustValue"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="@string/customerdetails" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_msetotList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_msecust"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >


                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/mse_lstCustGetCustomer"
                    style="@style/ListViewAppTheme.White"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                style="@style/textRegular_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lay_msecust"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:text="@string/orderdetails" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_mseorder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/mse_lstCustGetOrder"
                    style="@style/ListViewAppTheme.White"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_PO_mpr"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mse_btnCustGetCust"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mse_btnCustGetOrder"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mse_btnCustGetOrderDetails"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mse_btnCustExit"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want my layout to be stable (independent of data means even data is there or not it has to be stable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an "empty view" (e.g.: A view with a TextView with a default text, or a empty view with a fixed size to keep the ListViews separated) to be shown when `ListView` is empty (see [`setEmptyView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29)), or if don't want to show an empty view, increase the margin/padding between the ListViews.

Example:

Change your layout to:

```
...<!-- Previous part of your layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay_msetotList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_msecust"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mse_lstCustGetCustomer"
            style="@style/ListViewAppTheme.White"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             >
        </ListView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/custGetCustomerEmptyView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"<!-- Change this to your desired value -->
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        style="@style/textRegular_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lay_msecust"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="@string/orderdetails" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_mseorder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mse_lstCustGetOrder"
            style="@style/ListViewAppTheme.White"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            >
        </ListView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/custGetOrderEmptyView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"<!-- Change this to your desired value -->
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
...<!-- Rest of your layout -->
```

And then before you set the `ListView` adapter add:

```
custGetCustomerListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.custGetCustomerEmptyView));
custGetOrderListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.custGetOrderEmptyView));
```

EDIT:

To set sizes based on screen densities, you can create `values-<DENSITY>` (e.g.: `values-ldpi`, `values-xhdpi`, see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)) folders in the `res` folder of your project. Inside this folders create `dimens.xml` files with the size you want for that density.

Example dimens.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="list_view_empty_view_size">20p</dimen>
</resources>
```

and then on your layout set it like: `android:layout_height="@dimens/list_view_empty_view_size"`

or if you want to set it based on percentage:

Activity:

```
static final float LIST_VIEW_EMPTY_VIEW_SIZE = 0.2f;//20%

//on your onCreate method (or other where you initialize your views/variables
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point screenSize = new Point();
display.getSize(screenSize);

View custGetCustomerEmptyView = findViewById(R.id.custGetCustomerEmptyView);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)custGetCustomerEmptyView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = screenSize.y * LIST_VIEW_EMPTY_VIEW_SIZE;
custGetCustomerEmptyView.setLayoutParams(params);
//Repeat for your other empty view
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked for me.Is there any another way regardless of hardcoding my empty view to 20 dp @ Marco Batista

Comment: If you want different values based on screen density you can define different values on dimens.xml files, or if you want the view to occupy a % of the screen you can set the size of the code. Something like:

1. Get screen size
2. Multiply the size by the percentage you want
3. Set the empty view height

Comment: Can you please give some reference.

Comment: Thanks Marco...Really you taught me some great things:)

Comment: Glad I was able to help :D

Answer (score 0):

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_msetotList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_msecust"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"                
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >


            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/mse_lstCustGetCustomer"
                style="@style/ListViewAppTheme.White"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            style="@style/textRegular_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lay_msecust"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="@string/orderdetails" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_mseorder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/mse_lstCustGetOrder"
                style="@style/ListViewAppTheme.White"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want my listview to be visible even no data is there(as in image1).Will it works?@ Mohamed_AbdAllah

Comment: Sorry, I miss understood your question. In that case you need to give both LinearLayout Views 0dp height and set them to have equal weight.

Comment: Its okay but i tried the way you mentioned but doesn't worked.The layout coming like image 2 at run time.@ Mohamed_AbdAllah

Comment: Another solution is to give fixed height to the LinearLayouts containing the ListView. I don't know why the weight solution is not working. I have to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy paste the below code, and see if it works for you.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_green"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_mseTitle"
        style="@style/pageTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/mseTitle" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/txt_mseView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_mseTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#2E9AFE" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_msefull"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_mseView"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_mseOrder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >


            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/mse_radioCustImpBasedOn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/mse_radioCustOrderno"
                    style="@style/textRegular"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:button="@drawable/radiobutton_selector"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="@string/mse_order_no" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/mse_radioCustno"
                    style="@style/textRegular"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:button="@drawable/radiobutton_selector"
                    android:text="@string/mse_customer_no" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_msecategory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lay_mseOrder"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mse_custtxtCategory"
                style="@style/textRegular"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".27"
                android:text="@string/msecategory" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/mse_spnCustCategory"
                style="@style/SpinnerDropDownItemAppTheme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".23"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mse_custtxtfilter"
                style="@style/textRegular"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".27"
                android:text="@string/msefilter" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/mse_spnCustFilter"
                style="@style/SpinnerDropDownItemAppTheme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight=".23"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mse_edtCustValue"
            style="@style/EditTextAppTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/mseentervalue" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            style="@style/textRegular_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mse_edtCustValue"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="@string/customerdetails" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_msetotList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_msecust"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >


                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/mse_lstCustGetCustomer"
                    style="@style/ListViewAppTheme.White"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                style="@style/textRegular_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lay_msecust"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:text="@string/orderdetails" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_mseorder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/mse_lstCustGetOrder"
                    style="@style/ListViewAppTheme.White"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_PO_mpr"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mse_btnCustGetCust"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mse_btnCustGetOrder"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mse_btnCustGetOrderDetails"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mse_btnCustExit"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If not you will just have to wisely design the XML.